# Populate DataTable object using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have a DataTable object and I populate it in a foreach loop.

```
ForEach(DirectoryEntity dEntity in ListOfEntities)
{
Datatable.Rows.Add(dEntity.Name,dEntity.Age);
}
```

I want to convert this to linq. Please let me know how? I tried googling for 3-4 hours but unable to find any appropriate answer.

Comment: LINQ = Language integrated **query**.

Comment: I don't feel this question makes a lot of sense, really.

Comment: Maybe `ListOfEntities.ForEach(e => Datatable.Rows.Add(e.Name,e.Age));`. TBH you shouldn't be doing this, just use a simple `ForEach` that you're already doing; `linq` isn't correct to use here.

Comment: On another note, could you tell us what you're doing with this data, it will help us help you as there may be other alternatives to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: *I want to convert this to linq* -- Which part exactly? And why?

Answer (score 4):

If `ListOfEntities` is already from type `List<T>` you can do the following:

```
ListOfEntities.ForEach(entitiy => Datatable.Rows.Add(entity.Name,entity.Age);
```

If you `ListOfEntities` is only `IEnumerable<T>` you can do that:

```
ListOfEntities.ToList().ForEach(entitiy => Datatable.Rows.Add(entity.Name,entity.Age);
```

Only the `ToList()` is coming from `System.Linq` see here: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-5.0). The `ForEach` is defined on `List<T>` see here: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-5.0).

LINQ itself has no `ForEach`. LINQ is (as its name says) a query language. But you don't want to query data, you just want to execute an action.

Comment: So this isn't LINQ. Bottom line is, OP's code can't be converted into LINQ.

Comment: `ToList` would be LINQ but general speaking of course you are right: this isn't LINQ.
The question is what OP wanted to achieve. If we just wants to have small one liner instead the foreach the code will do it.

Answer (score 1):

entity.ForEach(fe => { dt.Rows.Add(fe.Item1, fe.Item2, fe.Item3, fe.Item4);});

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ConfigValue", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Rows.Add(25, "Ind", "David", DateTime.Now);
    dt.Dump("original datatable");

    var entity = new List<(int, string, string, DateTime)>();
    entity.Add((21, "isTrue", "false", DateTime.Now));
    entity.Add((100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now));
    entity.Add((101, "Hydra", "Christoff", DateTime.Now));
    entity.Add((50, "Christie", "Sam", DateTime.Now));
    entity.Dump("entities");

    entity.ForEach(fe => { dt.Rows.Add(fe.Item1, fe.Item2, fe.Item3, fe.Item4);});
//accept changes    
dt.AcceptChanges();
    dt.Dump("result");
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure how this is related to OP's question?